# external monitor unstable

Tags: kubuntu, lenovo, xrandr

I have recently attached an external monitor (Iiyama LCD) to my Lenovo T430S (Intel HD4000). Attaching went fine with the automagic setup etc., but the image on the external monitor is a bit unstable on light colours. It  looks like wobbly lines moving upward. It gives you a dizzy feeling when looking to long at it ;) I checked with xrandr  and all looks fine in the config. When I set up my external monitor as main and switch of the screen of the Lenovo all is stable again. It almost looks from my perception that the hd4000 can't cope with two screen. That seems unlikely as I also saw setups with two external monitors attached.

What could be the problem here and how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: what type of cable / connectors you use ?

Comment: hmmm that crossed my mind to. it is the default supplied (in the box) vga connector.

Comment: connecting to some other monitor fixed it... voting no-repro

Answer (score 1):

I think it must have also been a quality issue of the monitor. I plugged in a Dell U2413 Ultrasharp and everything is fine.